# Does a rotating magnetic monopole have an electric dipole?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles, dipole-moment

Does a rotating magnetic monopole have an electric dipole?

It is known that a rotating electrically charged sphere possesses a magnetic dipole, so *for symmetry* I guess that also a magnetic monopole has an electric dipole, but I cannot prove it.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole), the electromagnetic field of a particle with both electric and magnetic charge is given by:

$$F_{\mu\nu}=\partial\nu A_\mu-\partial_\mu A_\nu + \partial^\alpha \epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} P^\beta$$

I think that the potential $P^\beta$ should be given by a similar form to that of an electric charge:

$$P^0=\dfrac{g}{r}\quad P^i=0$$

where $g$ is the magnetic charge, however this form only gives the spatial components of the electromagnetic field tensor, so I guess this is wrong.

How do I prove that a rotating magnetic monopole has an electric dipole?

Comment: [Electric dipole expression for a rotating magnetic monopole](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0612266.pdf) is symmetrical to electron magnetic moment due to it's spin.

Comment: But **⯆⬝ß=0** , there are no magnetic monopoles?